# Why Jpa query bound parameters are dramatically slower than raw parameters with like clause?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, firebird, jaybird

When I execute query by setting parameter externally, query execution time is getting dramatically slow.

```java
StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
stopWatch.start();
Query nativeQuery = mEntityManager.createNativeQuery(
    "select first 100 * from ALL$ACC allacc0_ where allacc0_.code like ? order by allacc0_.code asc");
nativeQuery.setParameter(1, "FIMA%");
List resultList = nativeQuery.getResultList();
stopWatch.stop();
System.out.println(stopWatch.prettyPrint() + " Total row count: " + resultList.size());
```

StopWatch '': running time (millis) = **30868** Total row count: 4

```java
stopWatch = new StopWatch();
stopWatch.start();
Query nativeQuery1 = mEntityManager.createNativeQuery(
    "select first 100 * from ALL$ACC allacc0_ where allacc0_.code like 'FIMA%' order by allacc0_.code asc");
List resultList1 = nativeQuery1.getResultList();
stopWatch.stop();
System.out.println(stopWatch.prettyPrint()+ " Total row count: " + resultList1.size());
```

StopWatch '': running time (millis) = **10** Total row count: 4

Do you know why?

spring-data-jpa 2.1.3.RELEASE
jaybird.version 3.0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Firebird cannot optimize `LIKE` when a bind variable is used because it doesn't know what value you are going to use, so it has to assume the worst case and creates a plan that cannot use an index for the field.

On the other hand, when you use a literal that only ends with a `%`-wildcard (and doesn't contain wildcards `_` or `%` elsewhere), Firebird can optimize to use an index. For example, when you use `allacc0_.code like 'FIMA%'`, then Firebird will execute your query as if you used `allacc0_.code starting with 'FIMA'`, and [`starting with`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-predstartwith) can use an index if available.

If you want equivalent behavior with parameters, then rewrite your query to use `starting with` instead:

```java
Query nativeQuery = mEntityManager.createNativeQuery("select first 100 * from ALL$ACC allacc0_ where allacc0_.code starting with ? order by allacc0_.code asc");
nativeQuery.setParameter(1, "FIMA");
```

This is also documented in the Firebird Language Reference for [`LIKE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-predlike):

> #### About `LIKE` and the Optimizer
>
> [..] the `LIKE` predicate does not use an index. However, if the
> predicate takes the form of `LIKE 'string%'` , it will be converted to
> the `STARTING WITH` predicate, which will use an index.
>
> So—if you need to search for the beginning of a string, it is
> recommended to use the `STARTING WITH` predicate instead of the `LIKE`
> predicate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then "Spring Boot Data Query Method" List<AllAcc> findAllByCodeStartingWith(Pageable pageable, String aCode); is generating SQL Query wrong way.

Comment: @evracle That is possible, I'll add it to my things to investigate. It might help if you file an improvement ticket with Spring Data JPA and/or Hibernate on this.

Answer (score -1):

you should enable forced parameter support in DB level

[MS SQL](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2935/sql-server-simple-and-forced-parameterization/#:%7E:text=Forced%20parameterization%20is%20when%20the,there%20are%20a%20few%20exceptions.&text=Some%20applications%20use%20queries%20that,procedures%20that%20pass%20in%20parameters.)  Parameterization = FORCED

[Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/improve-sql-query-performance-by-using-bind-variables) CURSOR_SHARING = FORCE